# How can I get SWF file ,which gets its xml file via a coldfusion .cfm file, downloaded and work offline?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, coldfusion

I am trying to download the lesson player here(my.thinkwell.com/cf/external/?39B0F4357B39968D). I have downloaded the SWF file(http://thinkwell.cachefly.net/player/TWPlayer.swf). What I want is to make this file work on browser offline. I have downloaded the [page][1] source and edited the code in order for the SWF file to run, but nothing works. I've discovered that this SWF file communicates with a coldfusion file called config.cfm(thinkwell.cachefly.net/player/config.cfm) to get the [XML file of the lesson  which contains the lesson presentation files. I don't know how the process is exactly going and if there are other files included in the process. What I want to reach is to download all the files related to the whole process in order to be able to run it offline.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This doesn't seems to be a ColdFusion related issue.

Comment: If the swf talks to a coldfusion file, you'll need to have coldfusion installed for that file to run.

Comment: If you know the URL that is used to retrieve the XML, you browse to that URL and then save the response. However, you will need to update the .swf file (not easy to do without the source files) to read the file locally. Honestly, what you are trying to do does not seem 'above board' and could be a violation of the terms of use of thinkwell.com.

Comment: @ScottStroz This is because I want to build similar one, so I want to understand how are things going first. I need the file/response which lies between the XML file and the SWF file, this is exactly what I want.

Comment: @Anit Kumar: I reached that it is a ColdFusion issue from Firebug Net monitoring feature and I found a request for a .cfm file.

Comment: Still, might be a violation of terms of use.

Comment: Thanks for informing me about that.